# Cómo hacer la función de división recursivamente en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, recursión

Me gustaría hacer la función split (como la que indica el código) pero no tengo idea por donde empezar, por el momento solo tengo la versión no recursiva, la función no recursiva que tengo es esta:

```
def split(s,seps):
    temp = ""
    y = []
    for caracter in s:
        if caracter not in seps:
            temp += caracter
        else:
            y.append(temp)
            temp = ""

    y.append(temp)
    return y
```

Lo que quiero que haga esta función es de s, que es una cadena y seps, que es una lista de caracteres. Ejemplo :

```
sep = [',','.']
s= "ab,bv.bc,ad.ab"
```

La salida sería:

```
['ab','bv','bc','ad','ab']
```

Comment: Para empezar. Por que deseas una función recursiva? Yo creo que lo mejor en Python es evitar la recursión siempre que sea posible. Y segundo, que intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: Hola, es un ejercicio que me han planteado en un curso.Y lo segundo é realizado unos cambios respecto a esta versión iterativa para aplicar recursividad pero no me van, si hace falta os lo muestro.

Comment: Se supone que hace falta que lo muestres para demostrar que eres parte del esfuerzo por resolver tu propia duda y que no te hagamos la tarea. Sin embargo, alguien ya respondió...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con función recursiva es algo como esto:

```
def split(s, seps):
    if len(s) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(seps) == 0:
        return [s]
    else:
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[i] in seps:
                return [s[:i]] + split(s[i+1:], seps)
        return [s]

print(split("ab,bv.bc,ad.ab", ",."))
```

Comment: Gracias por tu intención! Pero por favor, no respondas preguntas donde el OP no demuestra esfuerzo por responder su propia duda. Además, no explicas como funciona el código que pusiste. El OP podría haberse llevado hecha la tarea sin aprender nada.